# Creating a efficient function that create one flat array from all values of all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I need a function in javascript that get all values from all kinds of objects and store in one single level array. I don't need its keys just values, but needs search for values recursively inside objects (HTMLElement and functions are considered a value, see tests for an example).

**IMPORTANT** - I'm **not** asking for transform arguments object into array. I want all values no matter how deep it is.

I've already wrote a function, but I want to know, if there is more effective way.

**Javascript Code**

```
//Helper function
function isString(obj){
  return (typeof obj === 'string' || obj instanceof String);
}
//Main function
function toArray(obj) {
  var k = Object.keys((obj || 0));
  var i = 0, l = k.length;
  if (isString(obj) || l == 0 || obj === window) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    var objs = [];
    while (i < l) {
      objs = objs.concat(toArray(obj[k[i]]));
      i++;
    }
    return objs
  }
}
```

**Tests**

```
var i, out,
arr = [{0: 2, 'car': 3}, {1: function(){}, 2:function foo(){}}, 1 ,'bar' , document.body, document.querySelectorAll('body'), window];
var s = performance.now();
for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  out = toArray(arr);
}
var e = performance.now();
//out: [2, 3, function, function, 1, "bar", <body>, <body>, 1, Window] (10)
//Passed in ~185ms (Safari 9.0.3)
```

Comment: What can you possibly need this for?

Comment: CodeReview.stackexchange.com is probably a better place to ask for suggestions for improvements to working code. SO is mainly for help with getting code working in the first place.

Comment: I have some functions that can receive all kinds of objects and I need turn into array and then I'll filter what I want. Thanks for the tip of codeReview, I looked into http://stackexchange.com/sites before post, and I simply not saw codeReview. I posted here because performance tag description.

Comment: I'd be more worried about cyclic references than performance... `a={}; a.b=a; toArray(a)`

Comment: @Vagner: the recursion line  objs = objs.concat(toArray(obj[k[i]])); is wrong because if you do not test for null you receive a error in console. Have you checked? Second: On my machine I get 840 millisecond, and my computer is not slow.

Comment: @Emissary good point, I really need check for this, do you have any hints? @gaemaf null problem, fixed, I changed `k = Object.keys((obj || 0));` now if `obj` is null or undefined  return it to array. Which is your browser and system? 840ms is a lot more than 185ms. Thanks guys.

Comment: `function flatten(a){ var b=[]; for (x of a) b.push(Array.isArray(x)?...flatten(x):x); return b;}` could you compare the perf with this, I expect it slower though